# Adapting formats between an sql database and a ploting service

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

im triyng to figure out an smart way to solve this problem. In my MySql server i have this simplified table:
[image]

As you can see, this is an statistic table, im interested on ploting how many visits (**profile_visit** under the *type* colunm) recived independently of the ip by each day from the begining of the data, that means that i have to query something like **WHERE type=profile_visit AND user_url=xxx**. But, this gives me a bunch of rows representing each visit made.

The question is, how can i use this raw data retrived from the query to obtain an array with the total visits by day (i dont care about time)?

Im using PHP, is a good idea to make the adaptation using a php script or it can be done using just MySQL querys?

If i reach the array with the total visits by day i can just simple adapt the format i need by:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".table_stats." WHERE user_url='xxx' AND type='profile_visit'");
        echo "data.addRows([";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $salida = $salida . "['".$row['date']."', $row['total']],";
        }
        $salida = rtrim($salida, ",");
        echo $salida . "]);";
```

Thanks for any help and orientation about this.

Comment: use GROUP BY id_user and COUNT(*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this directly from SQL that will run faster than retrieving the information from the DB and then processing it with php. The query should look like:

```
SELECT datetime, COUNT(id_stat) as numVisits WHERE type="type_profile" AND user_url = "xxx" GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(datetime, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

This will return the number of visits (numVisits) grouped by day, and the lowest datetime recorded that day.

I do not know if you want to display the information just showing the day. If so, you will need to use php to modify the string provided by the DB.

---

Using your example the result of the query is:

**datetime** | **numVisits**
2011-11-10 12:05:44 | 9
2011-11-12 20:06:06 | 3
...

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves every thing. But one question, changing the INTERVAL from 1 to 7 to 30 (like 1 day, 1 week or 1 month) doesnt change the result of the query. Whats the porpuse of this parameter? For me could be instereasting to have the possibility of different intervals, like daily, weekly and so. Thanks again!

Comment: @DomingoSL No, the structure of the result will not change. The INTERVAL parameter sets the _size_ in units of time (day, month...) of each group. you can even do INTERVAL 2 HOUR if you need it. Or as you said INTERVAL 1 MONTH or INTERVAL 30 DAY. It is really flexible

Comment: ok, but if i put INTERVAL 1 MONTH the result had to be 2011-11-12 12 ... intending 12 like 9 + 3 ???

Comment: @DomingoSL Well, almost, the result for INTERVAL 1 MONTH is **2011-11-10 12:05:44** 12, the query returns the lowest datetime of that month.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your after?

```
SELECT `tbl`.`ip`,COUNT(*) AS `visits` FROM `tbl` WHERE `tbl`.`type` = 'profile_visit' GROUP BY `tbl`.`ip` ORDER BY `visits`
```

This will return two columns, one with the IP and the other with the respective number of visits (all of type 'profile_vist').

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I read your question to quickly and missed the time parameter, you'll need something along the line:

```
SELECT
  `tbl`.`ip`,
  DATE(`tbl`.`date`) AS `date`,
  COUNT(*) AS `visits`
FROM `tbl`
WHERE `tbl`.`type` = 'profile_visit'
AND DATE(`tbl`.`date`) = 'date'
GROUP BY `tbl`.`ip`
ORDER BY `visits`
```

This will give you a summary on the specific date. If you don't need the IP, remove it from the SELECT-list and GROUP BY(DATE(`tbl`.`date`)) instead. To optimize, consider using DATE instead of DATETIME to avoid casting between the two (or adding an additional column).

Comment: I dont care about the IP, i need the total visits by day.

Comment: If you skip the `AND DATE` part of the WHERE clause, remove IP completely, you'll have just a count of the visits by day.